# How does Lists.newArraylist() of Guava library work?

Tags: java, generics, guava

I am trying to understand how `Lists.newArrayList()` knows the type of list to return.
I saw the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#79) for function `newArrayList()`, but it simply returns the `ArrayList` of generic type E.

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList() {
  return new ArrayList<E>();
}
```

However, when I call the function, I don't pass any such information.

```
List<String> testList = Lists.newArrayList();
```

How does it know what type of `ArrayList` I want?

I read about generics and `TypeToken` but could not relate to it through the code.

Comment: Please don't post live-code examples on Stack Overflow. Instead, re-write a self-containing and reduced code example from scratch that reproduces exactly the problem you want to ask about. Everything else is too broad. Also restrain from debugging requests and personal tutoring requests here on Stack Overflow. All you need to do is to formulate a concrete programming question, that's your entry-card.

Comment: These Guava APIs have been obsoleted by JDK 7 https://plus.google.com/118010414872916542489/posts/TtFEKhU8qnG

Comment: I wouldn't say obsoleted, those factory methods are a little more descriptive (`Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(5)` instead of `new ArrayList<>(5)`), and there's no good alternative for `Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c")`.

Comment: Thanks @staticx
I tried to add some code to make the question a bit more clear. The question is specific to a commonly used library and without knowing what it deals with, I couldn't be any more specific. So I hope this is more than personal tutoring and is concrete enough.
Stack is the only place for getting reliable answers for such queries.

Comment: The Guava APIs are better than the JDK7 collections. They don't break backwards compatibility with new syntax (old versions of Cobertura, Checkstyle, and other tools will bork on <>) and FACTORY METHOD is better than syntax sugar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the compiler can infer the type from the variable declaration.

Example:

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(),
```

the compiler will understand that the type of the collection (the type of E) will be `<String>`, since you expect to get a List of String.

It was useful to avoid rewriting entire <> arguments, but with Java7 and diamond operator you can avoid it using

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

(Imaginate it was a `List<List<String>>` you should rewrite `List<List<String>>`)

I found this for you:

> The Java compiler takes advantage of target typing to infer the type parameters of a 
>      generic method invocation. The target type of an expression is the data type that the Java compiler expects depending on where the expression appears. Consider the method Collections.emptyList, which is declared as follows:

```
static <T> List<T> emptyList();
```

> Consider the following assignment statement:

```
List<String> listOne = Collections.emptyList();
```

> This statement is expecting an instance of List; this data type is the target type. Because the method emptyList returns a value of type List, the compiler infers that the type argument T must be the value String. This works in both Java SE 7 and 8. Alternatively, you could use a type witness and specify the value of T as follows:

```
List<String> listOne = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

> However, this is not necessary in this context. It was necessary in other contexts, though. Consider the following method:

```
void processStringList(List<String> stringList) {
    // process stringList
}
```

> Suppose you want to invoke the method processStringList with an empty list. In Java SE 7, the following statement does not compile:

```
processStringList(Collections.emptyList());
```

> The Java SE 7 compiler generates an error message similar to the following:

```
List<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>
```

> The compiler requires a value for the type argument T so it starts with the value Object. Consequently, the invocation of Collections.emptyList returns a value of type List, which is incompatible with the method processStringList. Thus, in Java SE 7, you must specify the value of the value of the type argument as follows:

```
processStringList(Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

> This is no longer necessary in Java SE 8. The notion of what is a target type has been expanded to include method arguments, such as the argument to the method processStringList. In this case, processStringList requires an argument of type List. The method Collections.emptyList returns a value of List, so using the target type of List, the compiler infers that the type argument T has a value of String. Thus, in Java SE 8, the following statement compiles:

```
processStringList(Collections.emptyList());
```

> See Target Typing in Lambda Expressions for more information.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Comment: An important thing to note here is that `Collections.emptyList()` is an immutable empty list, hence it cannot be used as a replacement for the method the OP had.

Answer (score 4):

It can do so via type inference.

Simple put, you can have an assignment like:

```
List<String> list = newArrayList();
```

where `newArrayList()` probably is something along the lines of:

```
static <E> List<E> newArrayList() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Here the compiler will need to determine of what type the `E` type variable is. For this it will use the left hand side of the assignment, which consists of `List<String>`, hence `E == String`. Now it knows the type variable and everything is alright.

In contrary to using guava for such simple tasks, I would advise you to simply write:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would call it cleaner and no need for an (unnecessary) external dependence.

Comment: For the record, the diamond operator is introduced in Java 7, and Guava is targeted at Java 6+. The Guava authors in many cases do suggest using the JDK improvements that have since become available.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is [Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

Here's what's going on. You're not simply calling `Lists.newArrayList()`; you're also assigning it to a variable, like

```
List<Person> people = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Since you've specified the type arguments in the variable declaration, Java is able to "infer" (figure out) the type arguments you'd want in your new ArrayList, so you don't need to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler infers the type from the variable/method declaration.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html